# How to push a named volume / share a named volume with other **PCs**?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a container using the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
```

Now I want to share my work with my colleagues with all data in container. The main problem is I don't know how to share the named volume. I've read the manual and found named volumes can be used across containers. But what if across PCs? Can I just share the `/var/lib/docker/volumes/odoodocker_odoo-web-data/` directory to them?

Are there some elegant ways doing this?

Comment: They're the exact same ways you'd use to have a shared filesystem across systems *without* Docker. As such, "what are my options for shared filesystems?" isn't very much a software development question -- it's much more a system administration or OS-level configuration one, fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So did you mean if my colleagues and I running the exact same version of OS, a simple copy and paste directory will work?

Comment: "exact same version" may or may not matter. I was more aiming at whether all relevant systems have a specific network filesystem in common -- NFS or such (though if you're on a Windows-y platform, the native network filesystem is SMB). Appropriate selection also depends on whether you're looking for ongoing synchronization, and potentially other details that aren't at all Docker-specific or software-development-related or otherwise on-topic here.

Comment: have you tried to `docker save` or `docker commit`? i dont know if it saves the mounted files also.